# Socket.io - Trouble with disconnect event

Tags: events, socket.io, disconnect, emit

I want to append an li to a ul when a user disconects. (user has disconnected).

I don't know what's wrong with my code but I can't get the event to fire.

Here's my server.js

```
    socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
    users.splice(users.indexOf(socket), 1);
    console.log('User Disconnected: %s users connected.', users.length);
    io.sockets.emit('counter', {users : users.length});
 })
```

Which console.logs and counts the users without a problem. But when I try using the same call on the client.js:

```
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        $('#output').append('<li class="collection-item red-text">User has 
        disconnected</li>');
    })
```

Nothing gets appended to the UL. I'm probably missing something but can't see what. Any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you do to disconnect the socket in order to trigger the `disconnect` event on the client?  If the socket is just disconnecting when the page closes, then the page won't be able to display anything at that point.

Comment: It’s just when the page closes the disconnect event should be fired. I want the message to be shown to all other connected users that someone left.

Comment: The client side disconnect will not get to run when the page closes (the page has closed so it's not still running).  But the server-side disconnect event will get to run when the page closes so you can send to the other clients from the server.

Comment: How would I add the message for the other clients to see that a user has disconnected?

Comment: From  the server, `io.emit(msg, data)` will send to all connected clients.  Not sure what else you're asking.